# Can't set headers after they are sent when logging a user in

Tags: javascript, express, bcrypt

I'm scratching my head here, I'm using bcrypt to try and log in a user but I'm getting the following error:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Here's the code for that route:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: 'Auth failed'
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          res.json(200).json({
            message: 'Auth successful'
          });
        }
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: 'Auth failed 3'
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

I thought the error might've come from the `if else` statements and trying to send a header twice, but I'm ending them before moving on the next conditional no? Am I miss-reading something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is caused when your code tries to send more than one response for the same request.  The typical cause for this error is a coding mistake in how you handle asynchronous operations.  In your code you show, I can see the following mistakes that can cause this error:

1. If `user.length < 1`, then you do `res.status(401).json(...)`, but then you let the code continue to run where you then send other responses.
2. If you get an error from `bcrypt.compare()`, you send an error response and then let the code continue to run and send other responses.
3. If `bcrypt.compare()` succeeds, you send res.json(200).json(...) which is just wrong.  You probably meant `res.status(200).json(...)`.
4. If `bcrypt.compare()` succeeds and you have a `result`, you send two responses.

In looking at your code, it appears that you think that as soon as you do `res.json()` that the function returns and no other code executes.  That is not the case.  Until you hit a `return`, the rest of the code in that function continues to execute.

Here's one way to fix it (adding a few `return` statements and one `else`):

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec().then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) {
          res.status(401).json({message: 'Auth failed'});
          return;
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({message: 'Auth failed'});
            return;
          }
          if (result) {
            res.json({message: 'Auth successful'});
          } else {
            res.status(401).json({message: 'Auth failed 3'});
          }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    });
});
```

Or, to do this in a little cleaner fashion where all responses with the same status are combined and all flow control is done with promises, you can do something like this:

```
const util = require('util');
bcyrpt.compareAsync = util.promisify(bcrypt.compare);

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec().then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) {
            throw new Error('No user match');
        }
        return bcrypt.compareAsync(req.body.password, user[0].password).then(result => 
            if (!result) {
                throw new Error('Auth failed 2');
            }
            res.json({message: 'Auth successful'});
          }
        }).catch(err => {
            res.json(401).json({message: err.message});
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    });
});
```